# Issue while converting java object to byte array

Tags: java, arrays, string, object, byte

I am using reflection to get a object which contain string as value.Then i convert this object as byte array and saved to a file.
When i opened the file , there are some extra characters appended in front of the expected string.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Temp\\test.txt");
 Object obj = new String("Hello World"); //replaced reflection code with string object ,still not working
 fos.write(toByteArray(obj));
 fos.close();


public static byte[] toByteArray(Object obj) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            oos.writeObject(obj);
            oos.flush();
            bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        } finally {
            if (oos != null) {
                oos.close();
            }
            if (bos != null) {
                bos.close();
            }
        }
        return bytes;
    }
```

Output in the file:

[image]

Expected output in the file:

```
Hello World
```

I dont know why this extra characters appear in front of my original string, while converting object to byte array. Could you guys help me out here

Answer (score 2):

You are using an `java.io.ObjectOutputStream` object to write inside it a String.
You will not get as output in the file a human representation but rather a serialized form of the String.

To get a human representation of the `String` written in your output file, you should use rather `PrintStream` and use the method :  `public void println(String x)`.

Answer (score 1):

ObjectOutputStream#writeObject writes an object to an output stream by means of serialization. Serialization allows a developer to easily persist an object on disk or transfer it over a network.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject(java.lang.Object)

Hence, in your case it stores an instance of the String class instead of writing the characters of "Hello World",

I suggest reading up on serialization: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm